# High side switch

Tags: circuit-design

I am currently building a 24 V high side switch controlled by a 5 V Arduino NANO I/O.

Source: PLC 24 V out, 2 A (Max)
Transistors Available:
BC725 PNP
BC337 NPN
To drive an 1.7 V LED and to get 24 V signal back to the PLC.
below is the circuit that I tried, but comes with an observation that the LED was turned on already with I was testing it with power supply 24 V/100 mA without any 5 V input.

[image]

Any idea will be great, or did I do something stupid?

Thanks

Comment: The circuit looks ok although R11 and R13 seem rather small values, should be ok with 10k/22k.  Could something be feeding current in via R22?

Comment: R22 is the feedback that i want to send back to PLC I/O 1k Res is for limiting the current

Comment: Measure the voltage on R17 and base of the pnp transistor

Comment: The base of Q5 should be at 24V in the off state, if it is then perhaps disconnect R22 and see if the PLC is pulling the LED anode high

Comment: V17: 21.92V, Vbase - GND: 24.08V

Comment: If you disconnect the feedback connection to r22 does the led turn off?

Comment: i didn't connect R22 as i want test the LED with these two transistors first

Comment: Can you link a datasheet of BC725?

Comment: Sorry, i think i misunderstood, it's BC327-25 PNP transistor.

Comment: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/550008/ONSEMI/BC327.html

Answer (score 1):

R13 when pulled low draws 10 mA with 23V across it or 1/4W at burning hot temps . Change R13 to 10x R11.

R18 turns off LED until R19 is pulled high.